# Error compiling code for Android in Delphi

Tags: android, delphi

When I try to compile code for Android in Delphi, it shows this error:

> [PAClient Error] Error: E7688 Unable to execute '"C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.15.10-hotspot\bin\java.exe" -cp "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\bin\Android\r8-3.3.28.jar" com.android.tools.r8.D8 --release --min-api 23 --output "C:\Users\PC-Ney\Downloads\utils\Examples\Delphi\Android\Storage\Android\Debug\Storage.classes" @"C:\Users\PC-Ney\Downloads\utils\Examples\Delphi\Android\Storage\Android\Debug\dex_list.txt"' (Error 1)

I haven't found a solution for this.

I already tried using another SDK, but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: I suspect there may be additional information in the error messages after what you have provided.

Comment: I have exactly the same error. If you look inside dex_list.txt you will find a lot of files that should exist in "c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\android\*" (debug or release) but are not. Installation error? Maybe the files can be downloades somewhere.  

if you run the command outside the IDE you get: (copy the error message and edit it)
Error in c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\android\Debug\android-support-v4.dex.jar:
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\22.0\lib\android\Debug\android-support-v4.dex.jar

Comment: I tried installing both leaving Eclipse Adoptium out and including it. Same result

Answer (score 1):

Completely ignore my previous "answer" Do this:

1. Right click *Target Platforms*
2. Right click *Libraries*
3. Click *Revert System Files to Default*

After that, it should compile, link, merge, etc and deploy without error. The program I am migrating ran smoothly

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, since I used a previous version of Delphi (10.3)

1. I copied *dex_list.txt* to say *dex_list20.txt* (20 is the directory where Delphi 10.3) is installed
2. I replaced every instance of "22" with "20" so the files will refer to the Delphi 10.3 directory
3. I used *7z* to create a .7z file:
   `7z a 22 @path_to_dex_list20.txt`
4. Now, this file contains the missing files but also some old files
5. Expanded the file to
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\22.0\lib\android\debug`
   be extra careful not to overwrite any file already present. Just in case, copy the directory or make a 7z file before.

After this, my app compiled **but failed to deploy**, some INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED error but I guess that that has something to do with API version. I'm upgrading a 10.3 app to 11.1

Manually copying every nonexistent file should also work but I found this way more reliable.

Also, it's incredible, but many pages mention those Android Support Library files but not a single one stat how to get them. Google is making Android development more and more complex and less documented not to mention Embarcadero help, since my app, at first hand didn't even compile!

P.D. I don't know if there is a way to publish a file here or share it via some cloud storage link